# Logrotation help

Tags: 20.04, log, logrotate

I have custom logrotation as below..

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/apache
#
#
/var/log/apache/apache.log
{
        daily
        rotate 30
        size 1G
        compress
        missingok
        copytruncate
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s.log
}
```

here is the ls output.

```
ls -lrth /var/log/apache/apache.log*
-rw------- 1 root root 171M Oct 10 02:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696883462.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 121M Oct 10 05:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696894261.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 119M Oct 10 09:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696908661.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 143M Oct 10 13:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696923061.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 136M Oct 10 16:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696933861.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 132M Oct 10 19:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696944661.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 132M Oct 10 22:01 apache.log-2023-10-10-1696955461.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 161M Oct 11 02:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1696969861.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 145M Oct 11 06:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1696984261.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 137M Oct 11 11:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1697002261.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 120M Oct 11 13:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1697009461.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 118M Oct 11 15:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1697016661.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 134M Oct 11 19:01 apache.log-2023-10-11-1697031061.log.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 967M Oct 11 20:52 apache.log
```

So here is the problem.  I see Oct 10 logs in the rotated log file `apache.log-2023-10-11-1696969861.log.gz` and Oct 9 logs in `apache.log-2023-10-10-1696883462.log.gz`. I do not want that to happen. I want Oct 10 logs to be exclusively in apache.log-2023-10-10-***********.log.gz. Could you guys please guide, how to achieve it.

Comment: Since `logrotate` doesn't run at exactly midnight, and, since logs are buffered, you'll have to post-process the logs. On day N, you can easily process days N-1 and N-2, using normal text processing tools.

Comment: yeah @waltinator , that's what i am doing it now.. But it is becoming cumbersome for me, as the file name is not static..